# Loading MAPS(GIS) in python

Tags: python, maps, gis, geopandas, folium

I am new to GIS. So excuse me if I ask silly questions.
I want to load INDIA country map and want to plot various latitudes and longitudes offline.

These are the ways I know.

1. Using shape files and Geopandas, when I use matplotlib, it is not great and interactive, when I use geopandas.explore, it's not loading in spyder as it is web based.
2. When I use folium, it asks for active internet connection.

Questions:

1. Are there any better ways to load the map offline other than these two?
2. Where can I get shapfiles easily and for free usage?
3. In folium, how I do load the folium offline map saved in html and manipulate using folium itself. I mean, after loading the folium html file, can i added folium markers?
   In the below code, how I do load the "footprint.html" and add markers and others using folium?

```
import folium
mumbai_coord = [19,72]
m = folium.Map(location=mumbai_coord, zoom_start=9, position='relative', control_scale=True)
m.save("footprint.html")
m
```

Comment: Shapefile of what? Why interactive? IF you want something offline and interactive, use QGIS (a free application). You can also program your own function in Python. I use Python (mainly directly shapely and fiona, but sometime with geopandas (which uses both libraries) for some complex calculation (input geopackage, output geopackage, both will be probably used in QGIS). Else build a web app

Comment: Actually the requirement is to embed this map into a PyQt UI.